# Example of ill-formed implicit conversion

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

`N3797::13.3.3.1/2 [over.best.ics]` tells about an ill-formed implicit conversion as follows:

> Implicit conversion sequences are concerned only with the type,
>   cv-qualification, and value category of the argument and how these are
>   converted to match the corresponding properties of the parameter.
>   Other properties, such as the lifetime, storage class, alignment, or
>   accessibility of the argument and whether or not the argument is a
>   bit-field are ignored. So, although an implicit conversion sequence
>   can be defined for a given argument-parameter pair, *the conversion*
>   from the argument to the parameter *might still be ill-formed* in the
>   final analysis.

I have no idead about how can we ever define such a conversion. The thing is all kind of conversions I know are well-formed conversion like user-defined conversion with `operatorn A(){ ... }`  or a standard conversion. Couldn't you provide an example of the ill-formed conversion?

Comment: Perhaps something like a private conversion constructor from `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple example in §13.3.3.1.4 [over.ics.ref]/p4:

> [ *Example*: a function with an “lvalue reference to `int`” parameter
>   can be a viable candidate even if the corresponding argument is an
>   `int` bit-field. The formation of implicit conversion sequences treats
>   the `int` bit-field as an `int` lvalue and finds an exact match with
>   the parameter. If the function is selected by overload resolution, the
>   call will nonetheless be ill-formed because of the prohibition on
>   binding a non-`const` lvalue reference to a bit-field (8.5.3). —*end
>   example* ]